# .NET Framework 4.6 or a later update is already installed on this computer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to load a Visual Studio solution with .NET v4.6 projects in VS2013, but it tells me that I do not have this installed on my computer.

[image]

Which makes sense. So I tried to download and install this, from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137).
However, as soon as I fire up the installer, iT says: 
[image].

So now I'm stuck, because I can't load the project because I need to install something I can't install.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: You are missing the targeting pack, files in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies.  They tell the compiler what types and methods are implemented in 4.6.  Just skip forward to 4.6.1, the latest and greatest [is here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978).

Comment: Just my 2 cents: You can always install targeting packs (Developer Packs) for "old" versions of .NET to get it shown in  / supported by VS. For example, you can install Developer Pack for 4.6.1 even though you have 4.6.2 and 4.7 installed already, or even if you have installed 4.7 framework and no (skipped) 4.6 framework.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To develop for .NET 4.6 in Visual Studio 2013 you need to install the targetting pack for 4.6.

The .NET 4.6 you've got installed is enough to run the programs, but it is not enough for development.

So follow the advice of the dialog, download the targetting pack.

Note that what you said you tried to download and install, that wouldn't, was the normal runtime, and as you already know you have this installed. If you select the download option in the dialog it should open the right website, otherwise you should just open this page here (courtesy of [@HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in a comment):

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack and Language Packs for Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realised that the framework I had downloaded and the targetting pack were different things. :)

Comment: I am getting this same error message when trying to install on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have not installed 4.6.1 on this machine earlier. but it still says ".NET Framework 4.6 or a later update is already installed on this computer". Any thoughts?

Comment: Trying to install what? And have you checked if it is installed? Some other program may have installed it silently.

Comment: May be .NET Framework 4.7 is already installed. Thats why its complaining that a new version is already available.

Answer (score 5):

Installing the developer pack version fixed this for me:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @[Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) above, after installing the developer pack and updating the target framework to 4.6.1 the issue resolved. Find below the link to the setup:

[https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31721182)

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer that the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack installation and update to the target framework is required which is the resolution to the issue. Regarding the download link its pointing to Microsoft website and hope it stays alive.

Comment: Solved my issue, thanks! Link is dead, use this one instead - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49978